# Web scraping with Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, frameworks

I'm not able to find any good web scraping Java based API. The site which I need to scrape does not provide any API as well; I want to iterate over all web pages using some `pageID` and extract the HTML titles / other stuff in their DOM trees.

Are there ways other than web scraping?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

## jsoup

Extracting the title is not difficult, and you have many options, search here on Stack Overflow for "*Java HTML parsers*". One of them is [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

You can navigate the page using DOM if you know the page structure, see
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

It's a good library and I've used it in my last projects.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice library with no dependencies so it's quite lightweight. Also, it's headless so it doesn't need a browser (I've had problems with **Selenium** opening Chrome and I couldn't use **HtmlUnit** at all). **Selenium** must be more realistic but this library might serve the purpose in most scraping cases and it's really easy to setup: add the dependency and you're good to go.

Comment: Excellent library indeed. Easy setup and powerful regex support. doc.select("li[id^=cosid_]"). Cool.

Comment: I have recently open sourced my web scraping framework that not only allows you to parse the documents with Jsoup and HtmlUnit, but also handles the parallelization for you and can manage a large pool of proxy servers if required: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-webproxy

Comment: @subes can your framework be used for web analytics testing ?

Comment: My requirement is to do "Web Analytics" automation, is Jsoup can do all the testing activities ?

Comment: Well you can automate users coming from various parts of the world by creating proxy enabled bots (just web scrapers that navigate your analytics enabled website). Though be aware that some analytics packages filter users from public proxies. So better use a service for this or your own servers with proxies installed. Or you can navigate your analytics website itself and collect data for a dashboard there. So yes, but JSoup might not be enough for this since HtmlUnit provides cookies, JS and other essential support for this.

Answer (score 23):

Your best bet is to use Selenium Web Driver since it

1. Provides visual feedback to the coder (see your scraping in action, see where it stops)
2. Accurate and Consistent as it directly controls the browser you use.
3. Slow. Doesn't hit web pages like HtmlUnit does but sometimes you don't want to hit too fast.

   Htmlunit is fast but is horrible at handling Javascript and AJAX.

Comment: Adding here that to boost up the performance in Selenium Web Driver, you can use headless browser (Chrome, Firefox)

Answer (score 15):

**HTMLUnit** can be used to do web scraping, it supports invoking pages, filling & submitting forms. I have used this in my project. It is good java library for web scraping.
[read here for more](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 5):

mechanize for Java would be a good fit for this, and as Wadjy Essam mentioned it uses JSoup for the HMLT. mechanize is a stageful HTTP/HTML client that supports navigation, form submissions, and page scraping.

http://gistlabs.com/software/mechanize-for-java/ (and the GitHub here https://github.com/GistLabs/mechanize)

Answer (score 5):

There is also Jaunt Java Web Scraping & JSON Querying - http://jaunt-api.com

Answer (score 5):

You might look into [jwht-scraper](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scrapper)!

This is a complete **scraping** framework that has all the features a developper could expect from a web **scraper** :

- [Proxy support](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#proxy-finder)
- [Warning Sign Support to detect captchas and more](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#warning-signs)
- [Complex link following features](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#links)
- [Multithreading](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#parameter-parallelthreads-)
- [Various scraping delays when required](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#delay-and-waits-parameters)
- [Rotating User-Agent](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#parameter-rotatinguseragent-)
- [Request auto retry and HTTP redirections supports](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#parameter-maxrequestretries-)
- [HTTP headers, cookies and more support](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#http-parameters)
- [GET and POST support](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#parameter-method-)
- [Annotation Configuration](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#scraper-helper-annotations)
- [Detailed Scraping Metrics](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#get-metrics)
- [Async handling of the scraper client](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#scraper-client)
- [jwht-htmltopojo fully featured framework to map HTML to POJO](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-htmltopojo)
- [Custom Input Format handling and built in JSON -> POJO mapping](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#custom-object-mapper)
- [Full Exception Handling Control](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#exception-logger)
- [Detailed Logging with log4j](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-scraper#logging)
- [POJO injection](https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-htmltopojo#injection)
- Custom processing hooks
- Easy to use and well documented API

It works with (jwht-htmltopojo)[https://github.com/whimtrip/jwht-htmltopojo) lib which itsef uses Jsoup mentionned by several other people here.

Together they will help you built awesome scrapers mapping directly HTML to POJOs and bypassing any classical scraping problems in only a matter of minutes!

Hope this might help some people here!

Disclaimer, I am the one who developed it, feel free to let me know your remarks!

Answer (score 4):

Look at an HTML parser such as TagSoup, HTMLCleaner or NekoHTML.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to automate scraping of large amount pages or data, then you could try [Gotz ETL](https://github.com/maithilish/gotz).

It is completely model driven like a real ETL tool. Data structure, task workflow and pages to scrape are defined with a set of XML definition files and no coding is required. Query can be written either using Selectors with JSoup or XPath with HtmlUnit.

Comment: Asked 7 years, 6 months ago.

Answer (score 4):

For tasks of this type I usually use Crawller4j + Jsoup.

With crawler4j I download the pages from a domain, you can specify which ULR with a regular expression.

With jsoup, I "parsed" the html data you have searched for and downloaded with crawler4j.

Normally you can also download data with jsoup, but Crawler4J makes it easier to find links.
Another advantage of using crawler4j is that it is multithreaded and you can configure the number of concurrent threads

https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Normally I use selenium, which is software for testing automation.
You can control a browser through a webdriver, so you will not have problems with javascripts and it is usually not very detected if you use the full version. Headless browsers can be more identified.