# Guidance for getting text from a website and automating this everyday

Tags: java, text, web, automation, extract

I want to be able to extract text from a website everyday at a particular time. Instead of manually updating the text file myself everyday, I wish to automate this.

It would be really appreciated if you guys can guide me to what I should do and what skills I should learn to do this. I would preferably like to grab text using java, if there is a way.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to use grepsr since it requires very little skill:

https://app.grepsr.com/user/home

If grepsr does not work for you, follow this:

[Web scraping with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202305/web-scraping-with-java)