# Web scraping using Java

Tags: web-scraping

I want to show some part of my college site into my app (like news part only). Site is developed using JavaScript. Tell me how could I achieve this. I know Java quite well.

Comment: Hi there. This site is really for specific programming problems; if you are wanting to know the broad way in which to do something, there's no substitute for thorough research using a search engine. Start with searching your title - there'll be plenty of results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web scraping with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202305/web-scraping-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) and [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) that's all you need

Answer (score 0):

If you need javascript support, HtmlUnit is a very good solution for a headless browser. There also exists a framework that allows you to parallelize downloads over proxies using that: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-webproxy