# Best way to get some html data into Db - java

Tags: java, web-scraping

I want to program a java application, which will load data about flats from http://www.reality.sk/vyhladavanie.4 and store them into file or db.

What is the best approach to do that? What should I use to get data about every flat and how can I get data from other pages?

I thought about selenium and wrote some tests which will save all the data and click over all pages, but is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take a look into [web/html scraping with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202305/web-scraping-with-java)

For example, the table of the results has the class `search-result-ad-row`
and the title has class `title`, you should be able to extract the rest of the data in this way.

There are numerous ways to connect to a database, both through [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and ORM tools like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).   [Java File IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) is quite straightforward, but will depend on what format you want to store your data in.