# How do I get text content from a website with java?

Tags: java

According to my reference, this might work:

```
URL url = new URL("www.gmail.com");       
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    tr = in.readLine().toString();
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use all caps

Comment: And please put in the effort to ask a full and complete question, one with enough details to make it easy to answer. Please check out the [help] and the [ask].

Comment: See: [*Web scraping with Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3202305/642706)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a library like JSoup to get the body text from the HTML.

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment

```
String html = "<div><p>Lorem ipsum.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Element body = doc.body();
String text = body.text();
```