# Scrape data from a website that ranks first on a EAN/UPC google search

Tags: web-scraping, product, barcode, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I am curious whether the following automation would be feasible:

1. **search google** for a **UCP/EAN code** number (e.g. `8710103703631`)
2. **scrape** and parse data (depending on what is available) from the *first ranked page* concerning **Product**:

   - *Name*
   - *Brand*
   - *Model*
   - *Picture*
   - *Description*

Just trying to understand how complicated this might be.

Thank you!

Comment: That should be doable but I wouldnt advise scree-scraping. You could check out the python scrapy package, it could help you https://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup EAN/UPC codes via API

There are some [free web-APIs](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/barcodes) which (reverse-)lookup barcodes (EAN/UPC) or provide additional information.

For example [ean-search.org](https://www.ean-search.org/?q=8710103703631) is an REST API that is queried by the EAN and delivers XML (e.g. provides a link to Amazon for your sample "Philips Sonicare").

Benefit using an API: **ready to use data**, no scraping needed.

### Web-scraping for search-results

For sure you can use search-engines (like google, duckduckgo, etc.) and **search for the barcode** using the favorite **[web-scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) library** in your desired programming-language:

- **JSoup** (in Java): see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202305/web-scraping-with-java)
- **Scrapy** or **BeautifulSoup** (in Phyton): see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python)